# ElasticSearch Approximating GROUP_BY, SUM, SORT, with PAGINATION

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm using Elasticsearch and I see questions now and then about doing some aggregations with sorting or aggregations with paging, but I never see anything GROUP_BY, SUM, SORT, and PAGINATION together. If I were to write what I'm looking for as SQL, here it is (without the PAGINATION).

```
select invoice_date, address_2, company_name, sum(amount) 
from my_table 
group by invoice_date, address_2, company_name
order by sum(amount) desc
```

I tried doing this using many different techniques like composite aggregation, however it appears I can't do the ORDER_BY with this on the summation.

```
# composite aggregation
POST /746ee3a6-2b87-4288-9f20-3bf3a9e47e93/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          { "Address2": { "terms": { "field": "Address2" } } },
          { "Company_Description": { "terms": { "field": "Company_Description" } } },
          { "InvoiceDate": { "terms": { "field": "InvoiceDate" } } }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "summation": {
          "sum": { "field": "GrossValue" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried repeated nested aggregations but I saw a comment somewhere that with many nested levels you can't ORDER_BY either.

```
POST /746ee3a6-2b87-4288-9f20-3bf3a9e47e93/_search
{
  "size":0,
  "from":0,
  "sort":[{"Address2":"asc"}],
  "query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"taxonomy_full_code":-1}}]}},
  "track_total_hits":true,
  "aggs":{
    "agg0":{
      "terms":{"field":"Address2"},
      "aggs":{
        "agg1":{
          "terms":{"field":"Company_Description"},
          "aggs":{
            "agg2":{
              "terms":{"field":"InvoiceDate"},
              "aggs":{"sum(GrossValue)":{"sum":{"field":"GrossValue"}}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Same with multi-term aggregation

```
# multi-term aggregation
POST /746ee3a6-2b87-4288-9f20-3bf3a9e47e93/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "rule_builder": {
      "multi_terms": {
        "terms": [
          {"field": "Address2"},
          {"field": "Company_Description"},
          {"field": "InvoiceDate"}
        ]
      },
      "aggs":{
        "sum(GrossValue)":{"sum":{"field":"GrossValue"}}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Elasticsearch 7.14. Is what I'm looking for possible in this version?

Comment: Sorting is very limited in aggs to keep performance acceptable. Have you considered upserting "aggregated" docs with address, company and date, and adding the amounts on indexing? Then you'll have simple search instead of a heavy aggregation.

Comment: @ilvar, I've considered doing the aggregation in a database and from there inserting into ElasticSearch. I was hoping to avoid that approach for now until I get a little more time.